# How do I create and load an egg-file in Python?

Tags: python, setuptools, egg

I am researching for a way to distribute a python module as a single egg-file. Supposing I have a python module called `my_module` and I want to write a python script that generates an egg-file for my module. So I found `setuptools`.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="my_module",
    packages=[my_package],
    version="1.0",
)
```

And I've had some disadvantages regarding these issues:

1. This script should be run as `python setup.py install`. In other words, I need to specify command line arguments. Instead I want to generate my egg-file automatically during my python code, that has its own control over the command line arguments.
2. The result files are outputed into the setup's file directory. I would like to control the output directory path in the script.
3. The script create `build` and `dist` folders that I don't actually need. Probably, I could solve it by removing the folders after calling `setup`.

How should I use `setuptools` for my purposes covering the issues above?

And also how can I load my module from given egg-file?

---

Supposing I have a following module:

```
# my_module.py

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    def set_x(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def get_x(self):
        return self._x
```

I wrote this script to create an egg-file:

```
# create_egg.py

from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="my_module",
    packages=['my_module'],
    version="1.0",
)
```

I get such error, when I run `creage_egg.py`:

```
$ python3 create_egg.py
usage: create_egg.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: create_egg.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: create_egg.py --help-commands
   or: create_egg.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

Comment: This is a fine question, but a bit "too broad" for this site. If you slice the problem and ask about specific problems while trying to implement what you want, you will get better answers.

Comment: @PauloScardine Thanks for the advice. I'll modify my question in a while.

Comment: You should run `python3 create_egg.py bdist_egg`. run `python3 create_egg.py --help-commands` for additional commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing I found out is that a package must be a directory. So it's necessary to keep such structure:

```
my_project/
    my_module/
        __init__.py
    output/
    create_egg.py
test_egg.py
```

To skip the necessity of specifying the command line arguments there's a special option `script_args`. I found it here: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools

My `__init__.py`:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    def set_x(self, x):
        self._x = x

    def get_x(self):
        return self._x
```

My `create_egg.py`:

```
import os
import shutil
from setuptools import setup


OUTPUT_DIR = 'output'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        name="my_module",
        packages=['my_module'],
        version="1.0",
        script_args=['--quiet', 'bdist_egg'], # to create egg-file only
    )

    egg_name = os.listdir('dist')[0]

    os.rename(
        os.path.join('dist', egg_name),
        os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, egg_name)
    )

    shutil.rmtree('build')
    shutil.rmtree('dist')
    shutil.rmtree('my_module.egg-info')
```

My `test_egg.py`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('my_project/output/my_module-1.0-py3.5.egg')

import my_module


obj = my_module.MyClass()
obj.set_x(29)
print(obj.get_x())
```

Creating egg-file:

```
~/Stuff/my_project $ python3 create_egg.py 
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
```

Testing the module:

```
~/Stuff $ python3 test_egg.py 
29
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is an excellent [rubber-duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: Typically you write the call to `setup()` in a file called `setup.py`, which you then invoke as `python setup.py --quiet bdist_egg`, perhaps using a build tool like make. Having such a `setup.py` file in the root directory is what makes your project Pip-installable. If you have Pip (which you should on any recent Python version) you can simply do `pip install ~/Stuff/my_project` as long as `setup.py` is what and where PIp expects it to be. As an additional benefit, you no longer need to mess with `sys.path`.

Comment: Also consider using the Wheel format instead of the Egg format. See [here](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/wheel-vs-egg/) for a comparison (along with a lot of other good information).